# Limit verification

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} g(x)$ do not exist, does the

$\lim_{x\to 1}{ (f+g)}$,  exist? If so, how?

Comment: $f(x) = -g(x) = 1/(x-1)$ would do.

Answer (score 3):

$0=f-f$ so even if $lim_{x\to1}f$ may not exist....$lim_{x\to1}f+g$ can exist...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another suggestion using the [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html), take:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\ 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
Both are *nowhere continuous*, so $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 1}g(x)$ definitely don't exist.

However, for the sum you simply have $f(x)+g(x)=\ldots$, so ...